# Only accepting a WAI Websocket request if the user is logged in

Tags: haskell, authentication, websocket, haskell-warp

I am using [the wai-websockets package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-websockets) (version [3.0.1.1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-websockets-3.0.1.1)) and I would like to only open a socket if the user has already logged in.  I have a piece of middleware that takes care of all the authentication issues and if the user is logged in places a `User` record into the [`Vault`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#v:vault) of the WAI request.

Is there some way to access the WAI `Request` from the [`ServerApp`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-0.9.7.0/docs/Network-WebSockets.html#t:ServerApp), or in the alternative to inspect the `Request` before the it starts and pass the `User` value in?

Answer (score 0):

The following basic structure will allow you to analyze the `Request` before passing control to the websockets, and allow you to pass the `Request` value into your `ServerApp` if desired:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-9.3 script
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.Wai.Handler.WebSockets
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.WebSockets.Connection

main :: IO ()
main = run 3000 $ \req send ->
case websocketsApp defaultConnectionOptions _serverApp req of
    Nothing -> send $ responseLBS status200 [] "Websockets not supported"
    Just res -> send res
```